# Bash script to Rename multiple files in subfolder to their folder name

Tags: regex, bash, sed, batch-rename

I have the following file structure:

```
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_100/wrongname_120.nui; wrongname_200_d.nui
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_900/wrongname_120.nui; wrongname_200_d.nui
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_122/wrongname_120.nui; wrongname_200_d.nui
```

And I want to rename the fles to the same name as the directories they're in, but the files with "_d" at the end should retain its last 2 characters. The file pattern would always be "salford_xxx" where xxx is always 3 digits. So the resulting files would be:

```
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_100/Salford_100.nui; Salford_100_d.nui
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_900/Salford_900.nui; Salford_900_d.nui
Applications/Snowflake/applications/Salford_122/Salford_122.nui; Salford_122_d.nui
```

The script would run from a different location in

```
Applications/Snowflake/Table-updater
```

I imagine this would require a for loop and a sed regex, but Im open to any suggestions.
(Thanks @ghoti for your advice)
I've Tried this, which currently does not account for files with "_d" yet and I just get one file renamed correctly. Some help would be appreciated.

```
cd /Applications/snowflake/table-updater/Testing/applications/salford_*

dcomp="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
for file in *; do
ext="${file##*.}"
mv -v "$file" "$dcomp.$ext"

done
```

Ive now updated the script following @varun advice (thank you) and it now also searches through all files in the parent dir that contain salford in the name, missing out the parent name. Please see below

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#  RenameToDirName2.sh
#
set -e

cd /Applications/snowflake/table-updater/Testing/Applications/

find salford* -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec sh -c '(cd {}  &&
    (
        dcomp="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
        for file in *;
        do ext="${file#*.}"
            zz=$(echo $file|grep _d)
        if [ -z $zz ]
        then
            mv -v "$file" "$dcomp.$ext"
        else
            mv -v "$file" "${dcomp}_d.$ext"
    fi
done
)
)' ';'
```

The thing is, I've just realised that in these salford sub directories there are other files with different extensions that I don't want renaming. Ive tried putting in an else if statement to stipulate *.Nui files only, calling my $dcomp variable, like this

```
    else
    if file in $dcomp/*.nui
    then
     #continue...
```

But I get errors. Where should this go in my script and also do I have the correct syntax for this loop? Can you help?

Comment: So the filename is actually `wrongname_120.nui; wrongname_200_d.nui`, or are these two separate files in the same directory?

Comment: 2 separate files in the same directory. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are very happy to help you learn how to improve your craft, but somewhat less happy to serve as unpaid code monkeys.

Comment: @ghoti I tried this but I only was able to rename the two files into the dir name and not account for the _d. `cd /Applications/snowflake/table-updater/Testing/applications/salford_*

dcomp="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
for file in *; do
ext="${file##*.}"
mv -v "$file" "$dcomp.$ext"
done`

Comment: @Eggfoot - don't use comments for this, comments break formatting. Edit your question with the "edit" link below the question, then complete your question with a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without code in your question, the question is off-topic, since you're asking for recommendations rather then assistance with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eggfoot,I have modified my script, which will look into all the directories in folder applications and look for for folders which have Salford in it.
So you can call my script like this

./rename.sh  /home/username/Applications/Snowflake e/applications

```
#!/bin/bash
#    set -x
path=$1
dir_list=$(find $path/ -type d)
for index_dir in $dir_list
do
    aa=$(echo $index_dir|grep Salford)
    if [ ! -z $aa ]
    then
            files_list=$(find $index_dir/ -type f)
            for index in $files_list
            do
                    xx=$(basename $index)
                    z=$(echo $xx|grep '_d')
                    if [ -z $z ]
                    then
                            result=$(echo $index | sed 's/\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\(\..*$\)/\/\1\/\2\/\2\4/')
                            mv "$index" "$result"
                    else
                            result=$(echo $index | sed 's/\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)_d\(\..*$\)/\/\1\/\2\/\2_d\4/')
                            mv "$index" "$result"
                    fi
            done
    fi
  done
```

Regarding sed, it uses the s command of sed and substitute the file name with directory name, keeping the extension as it is.

Regarding your script,  you need to use grep command to find files which have _d and than you can use parameter substitution changing the mv for files with _d and one without _d.

```
  dcomp="$(basename "$(pwd)")"
  for file in *; do
  ext="${file##*.}"
  zz=$(echo $file|grep _d)
  if [ -z $zz ]
  then
  mv -v "$file" "$dcomp.$ext"
  else
  mv -v "$file" "${dcomp}_d.$ext"
  fi
  done
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Varun, could you give a breakdown as to whats going on in the sed regex's? Sorry Im still learning all of this. Also, the 3 digits after Salford_xxx folder names would be generated randomly, so could the argument for the script be:
./rename.sh /home/username/Applications/Snowflake e/applications/Salford_* ?

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
(
    cd ../applications/ && \
    for name in Salford_[0-9][0-9][0-9] ; do
        mv "$name"/*_[0-9][0-9][0-9].nui "$name/$name.nui"
        mv "$name"/*_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_d.nui "$name/${name}_d.nui"
    done
)
```

(Note: the `(...)` is a subshell, to restrict the scope of the directory-change and of the `name` variable.)

Comment: This appears to be taking the scope [0-9][0-9][0-9] as the actual file name and flagging the error "No such file or directory".

Comment: @Eggfoot: Since I don't have access to your box, I had to work with the information you provided in the question. Insofar as the situation on your box does not precisely match what's in the question, you may need to adjust the answer accordingly.